# how to make Google maps render immediately if it's below the fold in order to print it?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, printing, google-maps-markers

We have a relatively long page with a couple of Google Maps rendered via the JS API. Our app is Angular and we're using `ngx-print` to print a specific section in our page.

```
// eg.
const index = 0;
const latLngMapProperties = { ... };
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector(`.rowMap-${index}`), latLngMapProperties);
```

As the page scrolls down and the Google Maps come into view, I can see it render from the grey background to the actual road map. In the network tab, I can see it making calls to:

- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/ViewportInfoService.GetViewportInfo?
- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/QuotaService.RecordEvent
- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt
- bunch of SVGs

If I reload the page and print immediately (save as PDF), the maps don't show up. If  I scroll down so that it renders, then print, then the maps will show up.

Is it possible to make Google Maps render itself when it's loaded and below the fold? I don't want my users to have to scroll to the bottom before they can print properly.

Comment: Seeing the same in our React implementation. Even when rendering multiple maps the top ones will load, but those further down won't. Each map seems to decide for itself whether or not to render, seemingly without an option to toggle the behaviour.